# Trying to write a program to fill an array with random numbers in C

Tags: c, random

My issue is that I am getting segmentation fault (core dumped) each time I try, I have yet to clean up my code, but I am stumped.

I must enter the values in with the compiler e.g "./filename 0 100" whereby 0 is min and 100 is max.

It must then fill the array of 10 elements with random numbers (0-100). I am so close, just can't fathom the main function.

Also, how can I print the array {0,1,2,3} in format "[0,1,2,3]" including the commas, without it looking like "[0,1,2,3, ]"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getRandom(int min, int max);  
void fillArray(int data[], int size, int min, int max); 
void printArray(int data[], int size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;   
    int b;
    if (argc>=3){
        a = atoi(argv[1]);
        b = atoi(argv[2]);
        int arr[10];
        printf("\t An array with random values from 0 to 100 \n");
        fillArray(arr,10 ,a, b);
        printArray(arr, 10);
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments - please call with assignment min max\n");
    }
    return 0; 
}

int getRandom(int min, int max) {
   int result = 0;   
   int low = 0;   
   int high = 0;
   if (min<max) {
       low = min;
       high = max+1;    
   } else {     
       low = max + 1;   
       high = min;  
   }

   result = (rand() % (high-low)) + low; 
   return result;
}

void fillArray(int data[], int size, int min, int max){
   int i;
   for(i=min ; i < max+1; i++){
       data[i] = getRandom(min,max);
   }
}

void printArray(int data[], int size){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%d,", data[i]);
    }
    printf("]");
}
```

Comment: to print i usually do one statement for the prefix and 1st element, a loop for the remaining elements, and a final statement for the postfix, like this: `printf("[%d", a[0]); for (i=1; i<n; i++) printf(", %d", a[i]); printf("]\n");`

Comment: For this: `printf("\t An array with random values from 0 to 100 \n");` don't you mean to pass `a` and `b` as your min/max values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Steve Friedl that the main problem with your program lies in the `fillArray` function. There `i` should run from `0` to `size`.

As for your second question, testing whether you're printing the last number helps to suppress the unwanted comma:

```
void printArray(int data[], int size) {
    printf("[");   
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d", data[i]);
        if (i < size - 1)
            printf(",");
    }   
    printf("]");
}
```

If you prefer a more compact solution (although with an optimizing compiler there's not really a difference), you could write it as:

```
void printArray(int data[], int size) {
    printf("[");   
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d%c", data[i], i < size-1 ? ',' : ']');
    }
}
```

Also, in your main function, you should include `a` and `b` in your printing:

```
printf("\t An array with random values from %d to %d \n", a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is blowing things up for you:

```
void fillArray(int data[], int size, int min, int max){
   int i;
   for(i=min ; i < max+1; i++){   // <-- HERE
       data[i] = getRandom(min,max);
   }
}
```

The calling function allocates 10 items in the `arr` array, and that's passed as the `size` parameter, but you're not using that parameter to limit filling up the array. If the `max` value is 100, then it's trying to fill *one hundred* slots instead of just ten.

```
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      data[i] = getRandom(min,max);
```

should fix at least this issue.

EDIT: The comma thing, I prefer to add commas *before* the items unless this is the first. In this case it doesn't matter much, but it's more general, especially for variable-length lists where you don't know you're at the end until you get there. Augmenting the helpful response from @JohanC :

```
void printArray(int data[], int size) {
    printf("[");   
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i > 0) printf(",");
        printf("%d", data[i]);
    }   
    printf("]");
}
```

Comment: Great thank you, will tweak my code shortly and hope for the best.